# What is the actual way of negating a mathematical statement?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> For each $x \gt 0$ and $y \in \Bbb R,$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx \gt y.$

How to negate the above statement? I am doing in the following way $:$

**There exists $x \leq 0$ or $y \notin \Bbb R$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$ we have $nx \leq y.$**

But I don't think it's a valid negation. Actually I don't know what's the actual way to negate a statement. Is there any certain rule which can be used in order to negate any mathematical statement? Also I have just heard the word "quantifiers". Can anybody please clear it to me about the role of "quantifiers" here? What does that actually mean?

Any suggestion regarding this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Slowly. The actual way of doing anything in mathematics is slowly. Perhaps slowly and methodically.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila may I know what's your slow and methodological way?

Comment: Apply the negation, and use the theorems that simplify negations (e.g. $\lnot\forall x\varphi\iff\exists x\lnot\varphi$) one step at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposition should be written as

$$(\forall (x,y)\in \Bbb R^+\times \Bbb R)\; (\exists n\in \Bbb N) \;:$$
$$\;nx>y$$

and its negation will be

$$(\exists (x,y)\in \Bbb R^+\times \Bbb R)\;:\;(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\;$$
$$nx\le y$$

Comment: Why isn't the negation as follows: "there exists some $x > 0$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, for which there is no $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx > y$." Is your answer equivalent or different?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine Exactly equivalent.

Comment: But negation of "$A$ and $B$" is "Neither $A$ nor $B$." Right?

Comment: Can I convert this into the statement $A \implies B\ $? Then it's negation will be $A \implies$ not  $B.$

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine if the negation of "**$A$ and $B$**" is "**Neither $A$ nor $B$**". Then why doesn't the negation of "**For each $x \gt 0$ and $y \in \Bbb R$ ...**" imply "**There exists $x \leq 0$ or $y \notin \Bbb R... ?$**"

Comment: @Phibetakappa "A implies not B" is **not** the negation of "A implies B." Indeed, both of those statements can be true simultaneously (namely, if A itself is false then they're both vacuously true). In fact, the negation of "A implies B" is "A and not B."

Comment: @Phi beta kappa Because this "and" is not logical $\land$ "and", but a conjunction of quantification: It means "For each $x \land 0$, for each $y \in \mathbb{R} ...$. Negation on this kind of construction works differently than with $\land$.

Comment: @Noah Schweber I don't get your point. Can you please be more explicit?

Comment: @Phibetakappa You wrote "Can I convert this into the statement $A\implies B$? Then its negation will be $A\implies$ not $B$." But the second sentence there is false: the negation of "$A\implies B$" is **not** "$A\implies$ not $B$."

Comment: For that matter, your earlier comment "But negation of "$A$ and $B$" is "Neither $A$ nor $B$." Right?" is also wrong: the negation of "$A$ and $B$" is "Either (not $A$) or (not $B$)."

Comment: @Noah Schweber why doesn't the negation "$A \implies B$" imply "$A \implies$ (not $B$)" but "$A\ \land$ (not $B$)? Can you please clear it to me by means of giving a counter-example? May be you can provide your thoughts in the form of an answer, if you wish. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A condition $P(x)$ on a quantified variable $x$ can be moved to the statement following the quantifier as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\forall x\ P(x) : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \forall x : P(x) \implies Q(x) \\
\exists x\ P(x) : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \exists x : P(x) \land Q(x)
\end{align}$$
For example,
$$\begin{align}
\forall x>0 : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \forall x : x>0 \implies Q(x) \\
\exists x\in \mathbb{N} : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \exists x : x\in\mathbb{N} \land Q(x)
\end{align}$$

By the laws of negating quantifiers,
$$\begin{align}
\neg\forall x \text{ s.t. }P(x) : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \exists x : \neg(P(x) \implies Q(x)) \\
\neg\exists x \text{ s.t. }P(x) : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \forall x : \neg(P(x) \land Q(x))
\end{align}$$

Now remember the negation laws of implication and conjunction:
$$\begin{align}
\neg(P \implies Q) &\quad\equiv\quad P \land \neg Q\\
\neg(P \land Q) &\quad\equiv\quad \neg P \lor \neg Q
\end{align}$$

Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\neg\forall x \ P(x) : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \exists x : P(x) \land \neg Q(x)  &\quad\equiv\quad \exists x\ P(x) : \neg Q(x) \\
\neg\exists x \ P(x) : Q(x) &\quad\equiv\quad \forall x : \neg P(x) \lor \neg Q(x)  &\quad\equiv\quad \forall x\ P(x) : \neg Q(x)
\end{align}$$

The given statement "For each $x \gt 0$ and $y \in \Bbb R,$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx \gt y$" can be written
$$
\forall x>0\ \forall y\in\mathbb{R}\ \exists n\in\mathbb{N} : nx>y
$$
so the negation is
$$
\exists x>0\ \exists y\in\mathbb{R}\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N} : nx\leq y
$$

Comment: What does $P(x) : Q(x)$ mean? Can you please suggest me a book which elaborates these facts in an explicit way?

Comment: @Phibetakappa. The statement like "there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $nx>y$ can be written as $\exists n\in\mathbb{N} : nx>y$. I needed some notation for generalization of the part $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}$ and decided to write it as $\exists n\ P(n),$ where $P(n)$ in this case is $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ So $\exists x\ P(x) : Q(x)$ should be read as "there exists $x$ satisfying $P(x)$ such that $Q(x)$."

Comment: @Phibetakappa. The predicate $P(x)$ is used for the conditions like $x>0$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa. Perhaps it would have been better to write all those conditions as set membership, e.g. $\exists x\in(0,\infty)$ for $\exists x>0$ and then translate $\exists x\in A : Q(x)$ to $\exists x : x\in A \land Q(x).$

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the negation of this statement is just

> It is not the case that for each $x \gt 0$ and $y \in \Bbb R,$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx \gt y.$

-- but usually these kinds of exercises expect you to push the negation inside as far as possible to arrive at a logically equivalent ($\equiv$) statement.

Quantifiers are operators that, well, quantify elements. "for all" and "there exists" are quantifiers. ("for all" and "for each" mean the same.) Other examples of quantifiers include "no", "not all", "exactly 2" or "at least 3".
Quantifiers often come with a so-called restriction, which limits which objects the quantifier ranges over, e.g. the $x > 0$ after the "for each" and the "$y \in \mathbb{R}$" after the "and" in your example.
In general, you don't negate the restriction of the quantifier, but only the part that follows it. So you don't e.g. turn $x > 0$ into $x \leq 0$, because that's just part of the restriction, but instead you pass the negation to the part after "for each $x > 0$".

The rules for negating quantifiers are as follows:

- not (for all x) $\equiv$ there exists an x such that not
- not (there exists an x) $\equiv$ for all x not
- not (no x) $\equiv$ there exists an x such that

The rules for pushing negations of logical operators inside are:

- not (A and B) $\equiv$ (not A) or (not B)
- not (A or B) $\equiv$ (not A) and (not B)
- not (if A then B) $\equiv$ (A) and (not B)
- not (A if B) $\equiv$ (not A) and (B)
- not (A if and only if B) $\equiv$ ((A) and (not B)) or ((not A) and (B))

In addition, there are special negations of some arithmetic operations:

- not ($x = y$) $\equiv$ $x \neq y$
- not ($x \geq y$) $\equiv$ $x < y$
- not ($x > y$) $\equiv$ $x \leq y$

Double negations get eliminated:

- not not A $\equiv$ A

Finally, quantification with "and" is in fact two nested quantififactions:

- for all x and y $\equiv$ for all x for all y
- there exists x and y such that $\equiv$ there exists x such that there exists y such that

---

And now just apply these rules to your sentence step by step -- this is a purely mechanical procedure, just follow the negation through until there are no more rules to apply.

> not for each $x \gt 0$ **and** $y \in \Bbb R,$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx \gt y$
> $\equiv$ **not** for each $x \gt 0$ for each $y \in \Bbb R$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx \gt y$
> $\equiv$ there exists $x \gt 0$ such that **not** for each $y \in \Bbb R$ there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx \gt y$
> $\equiv$ there exists $x \gt 0$ such that there exists $y \in \Bbb R$ such that **not** there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $nx \gt y$
> $\equiv$ there exists $x \gt 0$ such that there exists $y \in \Bbb R$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$ **not** $nx \gt y$
> $\equiv$ there exists $x \gt 0$ such that there exists $y \in \Bbb R$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$ $nx \pmb{\pmb{\leq}} y$
> $\equiv$ there exists $x \gt 0$ and $y \in \Bbb R$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $nx \leq y$

In semi-formal notation:

> $\exists x \gt 0\ \exists y \in \Bbb R\ \forall n \in \Bbb N: nx \leq y$

In formal notation:

> $\exists x (x \gt 0 \land \exists y (y \in \Bbb R \land \forall n (n \in \Bbb N \implies nx \leq y)))$

Comment: very nice answer. I want to know can the given statement be written in $A \implies B$ form?  I am also thinking about the negation of continuity of a function $f$ at a point. Can the continuity of a function $f$ at a point be thought of as a statement of the form $A \implies B\  ?$

Comment: What do you mean by "in $A \implies B$ from"? Are you referring to the answer by md2perpe?

Comment: I mean there are essentially two parts in the statement; one is the independent part of the statement on which another part of the statement is dependent.

Comment: I edited the end of my post -- is this what you mean?

Comment: In formal notation you introduce round brackets in a tricky way. How to use those notations in an efficient way? Is there any book which elaborates this fact explicitly?

Comment: It's not all that tricky, I just bracketed everything after a $\exists x$ or $\forall x$ to make clear that the quantifier ranges over the rest of the statement. Notation also varies between textbooks. I don't know off the top of my head which book focuses in particular on translation exerises, but I think that would make for a good new question to post.

Comment: How to negate something in formal notation? Is it the same rule? Here can I negate "or" , "and" inside the parenthesis? I am in a fix. Notations confuse me a lot.

Comment: Can I replace $\land$ by $\lor$ and vice-versa within the parentheses while negating a statement in formal notation?

Comment: The same rules apply in formal notation: $\neg(A \land B) \equiv \neg A \lor \neg B$ and $\neg(A \lor B) \equiv \neg A \land \neg B$.

Comment: But then $\exists x (x \gt 0 \land \exists y (y \in \Bbb R \land \forall n (n \in \Bbb N \implies nx \leq y)))$ negates to $\forall x (x \gt 0 \lor \forall y (y \in \Bbb R \lor \exists n (n \in \Bbb N \land nx \geq y))).$ How does it look like if we convert it into literature?

Comment: No, its negation is $\forall x (\neg (x > 0) \lor \forall y (\neg (y \in \mathbb{R}) \lor \exists n  (n \in \mathbb{N} \land \neg (nx \leq y)))$, and this is logically equivalent to  $\forall x (x > 0 \implies \forall y (y \in \mathbb{R} \implies \exists n  (n \in \mathbb{N} \land (nx > y)))$, as desired.

Comment: But in your answer you have **clearly mentioned** that while negating a quantified argument we don't negate the restrictions imposed on the underlying quantified variables. So why in this case do you negate the restrictions $(x \gt 0)$ and $(y \in \Bbb R)\ $? Your argument seems ambiguous to me.

Comment: I also don't understand how do you convert $\lor$ to $\implies.$ Where do you get all those things? Your answer cannot be acceptable unless you provide some reference supporting your arguments. I can't accept them blindly. I'm really sorry for that. I think that's the reason why your answer is not upvoted by a single person in this site due to lack of clarity.